# Values from document.form in email

Tags: html

on my website I have some text forms. Now I want to create a button with a mailto, which includes the value input in the document.forms

For example

Some types in in input field Name: Steven

Then Steven should appear in the body, after klick on the mailto button.

How can I solve this?

```html
<form>
  <strong>
<br />
Here:</strong> <br />
  <br />
  <table width="100%" align="left">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div align="left"> Name</div>
      </td>
      <td><input type="text" size="6" name="alpha" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>

<a href="mailto:info@abc.com?subject=name!"> Click here!</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use parameters like `subject` and `body`

```html
<a href="mailto:some-name@gmail.com?subject=hello&body=this is the body">click to open mail</a>
```

[Read more about E-mail links here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Introduction_to_HTML/Creating_hyperlinks#e-mail_links)

Now if you want to add content from an input field to the email you can use a little javascript to concatenate content as string to the body of the email like:

```js
var mailtoElement = document.querySelector('a[href^="mailto"]');
mailtoElement.addEventListener('click', function() {
    var alphaValue = 'Name: ' + mailtoElement.closest('form').querySelector('input[name="alpha"]').value;
    mailtoElement.href = mailtoElement.href + '?subject=xxx&body=' + alphaValue;
});
```

```html
<form>
<strong>
  <br />
  Here:</strong> <br />
  <br />
  <table width="100%" align="left">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div align="left"> Name</div>
      </td>
      <td><input type="text" size="50" name="alpha" placeholder="Type Name before click" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <a href="mailto:some-email@gmail.com">click to mail form</a>
</form>
```

Comment: thanks, but how can I add the value from the input form to the body of the email?

Comment: nice, sorry but I am newbie.. how can I integrate now to my html code? Do I have to put the Javascript into <script> tags? any other requirements?

Comment: @arbess yes all javascript inside `<script>HERE</script>` and you must place it after the `<a href="mailto...` element, or in this case maybe even nicer to place it right after the closing `</form>` tag

Comment: @arbess I just checked your profile. Please if questions are answered and solved [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86978/how-do-i-accept-an-answer-on-stackoverflow) . if it is not solved comment and let us know what is missing